# 15-250 regex validation

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I'm trying to build up some regular expressions to validate a textbox on c# wpf. I build the following to validate a number from 6 to 3600:

```
^([6-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,2}|[12][0-9]{3}|3[0-5][0-9]{2}|3600)$
```

Now I need to validate from 15 to 250. I am new on regex and I am having a hard time getting it.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use `int.TryParse` and check the the integer?

Comment: regex not used for this!!

Comment: A numeric updown would be a far better fit.

Comment: Are you saying that you found the 6 to 3600 regex somewhere and don't know how it works? Because although regex is an odd choice for this task, the principle behind that regex could easily be applied to any range.

Comment: I found the one from 6 to 3600, now I am trying to do 15 to 250

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct translation would be:

```
^(1[5-9]|[2-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|250)$
```

Split up it is `1[5-9]` or 15-19, `[2-9][0-9]` or 20-99, `1[0-9]{2}` or 200-199, `2[0-4][0-9]` or 100-249, `250`.

Answer (score 1):

You want the number validated from 6 - 3600 and another 15 - 250? why not just convert the number to int and check the min and max?

Take a look at the following to correctly implement validation in WPF
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Agreed, but its an answer to go in a different direction than to use Regex for number validation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good read for [Matching Numeric Ranges with a Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html)

The Regex for 15 to 250 would be

```
^(1[5-9]|[2-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|250)$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lE8uN9/3)**

Comment: That link deserves to be the centrepiece of your answer (with a summary of the key points so that the answer stands alone), not an afterthought.

Comment: @IMSoP:- Updated my answer with the Regex!

Answer (score 0):

The following RegEx should satisfy all numbers in the range 15-250. However, as I have cautioned you in the comments, a NumericUpDown is a far superior choice for this kind of stuff:

```
\b(2[0-4]\d)|(1\d\d)|(250)|([2-9]\d)|(1[5-9])\b
```

Comment: dotNet This works for the values less than 15 but it is not working for the values higher than 250.

Comment: @user3614070:- Updated the regex. Check my answer with the Regex Demo!